# Google chart's bars, column or area overlap axises when automatic default baseline are greater than 0 in iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-visualization

I have this issue in EDGE and IE browsers, when the chart is in iframe and the range of data are with close values. Is there someone with the same problem and how to solve it?

Sample code from documentation with close values:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Data'],
         ['01',  13500],
         ['02',  13500],
         ['03',  13500],
         ['04',  13900],
         ['05',  13900],
         ['06',  11900],
         ['07',  13900],
         ['08',  13900],
         ['09',  13900],
         ['10',  12300],
         ['11',  13900],
         ['12',  13500]
      ]);

    var chart = new  google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {});
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tki90.png)